# three vector fields with zero Lie bracket

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose I have three unit vector fields $u, v, w$ on a two-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Are there simple compatibility conditions relating $v$ and $w$ such that there exists scalar fields $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ with
$$[\alpha u, \beta v] = [\alpha u, \gamma w] = 0?$$

If you have just two unit vector fields $u, v$, you can always find such an $\alpha, \beta$ (in fact you can fix $\alpha, \beta$ along an integral curve of $u$ and $v$, respectively, and then first-order ODEs uniquely determine their values everywhere else. Intuitively, you specify two "sides" of a checkerboard and then fill in the rest of the board by advection.)

But if you also include the third vector field a nontrivial solution generally will not exist.